# ASP.NET Automation Issues

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

I'm trying to use a command-line client to automate some work on an ASP.NET based website and have run into an issue with authentication that I've never seen before and am wondering if anyone else has.

When I pull out my browser inspection tools I notice "login.x" and a "login.y" values posted that are integer values and change every time I perform the post. However there is no HTML Input element by either of those names.

I've scanned the JavaScript associated with the site but have not yet found anything manipulating the POST data. I need to do more digging on that though to make sure.

I think that those values are used as additional security measures to prevent screen scraping or automated access but I'm not 100% certain. The Goog doesn't do particularly well searching for "login.x" because it translates the '.' to either a space or a hyphen depending on whether I'm in the basic or advanced search panels.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: .x and .y are the coordinates for your clicks, presumably on a control you have named "login".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That are coordinates of the button you've used for the login button. It's of no consequence. They only tell the x/y coordinates the user clicked on.